# Laravel Toolkit change default version

Tags: laravel, plesk

I am installing Laravel using the Laravel toolkit in my Plesk panel, but it installs version 8.83.27 by default, and I cannot perform an installation above this version. I want to install Laravel 10.x. Can you help me with this?

composler.lock change

Comment: goto ```composer.json``` then replace the **require** to this ```"require":"laravel/framework": "^10.*" },```. Then run ```composer update```.